# valueChangeListener not invoked when input validation fails

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

In selectOneMenu when validation fails against f:validator,f:attribute, the valueChangeListener is not getting invoked ,I tried immediate="true" also but it didn't work out.
Any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks.
Below is the code snippet:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="firstinputselectone"   rendered="#{!dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.singleProfile}"
                        valueChangeListener="#{dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.showLayoutPreview}" 
                        styleClass="#{extraFieldDTO.isReadOnly eq '1' ?'disabledInputFieldSelectItem' :'enabledInputFieldSelectItem'}"
                        disabled="#{extraFieldDTO.isReadOnly eq '1'}"
                        value="#{extraFieldDTO.stringFieldValue}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.DROP_SELECTONE}"
        id="selectItem_24" />

    <f:selectItems
        value="#{dropDownParserAction.getGenericLinkedKeyValueListMap(null,extraFieldDTO.dropDownSearchValue,extraFieldDTO.dropDownType,extraFieldDTO.firstLinkedDropDownType)}"
        id="selectItems_24655" />
    <p:ajax event="change" id="ajax_2" update="@form" />
    <f:validator validatorId="dynamicUIValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="DYNAMICUIDATAOBJECT" value="#{extraFieldDTO}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

```
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </p:fieldset>
                                <p:spacer width="50" />
                                <p:fieldset legend="#{msg.LBL_BACKCARD}" toggleable="false"
                                    style="width:400px;height:400px;background-color:#e6e6e6">
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        <br clear="none" />
                                        <br clear="none" />
                                        <br clear="none" />
                                        <br clear="none" />
                                        <p:spacer height="40" />
                                        <h:graphicImage id="layout_present_idar590" rendered="#{dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.backProfileLayout ne null}"
                                            value="data:image/jpg;base64,#{dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.backProfileLayout}" />

                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </p:fieldset>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </div>
                    </p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: If validation fails, then there's simply no means of a new value, so it's logical it won't be invoked. What exactly is your functional requirement? I.e. what problem exactly are you trying to solve with the value change listener? If you never use the event.getOldValue(), then it's definitely the wrong tool for the job. If you elaborate the desired job, then we can propose the right way to achieve that.

Comment: yup you are correct @BalusC, but my requirement was that depending on the selection I was rendering some layouts(which have one-to-one relationship) with the selected dropdown and if we select the selectOneMenu the previous layouts should not be rendered .But since validation fails I was not able to reset the layouts.Anyway I got the workaround for that by using  rendered="!facesContext.validationFailed" in the layouts panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks, I got the workaround for this by using rendered="!facesContext.validationFailed" in the layouts panel which was not supposed to be rendered when validation fails.
Here is the code snippet:



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

            <p:tabView
                rendered="#{extraFieldDTO.fieldType.equals('IDENTITY_CREDENTIAL')}">
                <p:tab title="#{msg.LBL_IDENTITY_CREDENTIAL}">
                    <br clear="none" />
                    <br clear="none" />
                    <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
                    <h:panelGroup
                        rendered="#{extraFieldDTO.fieldType.equals('IDENTITY_CREDENTIAL')}">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;"
                            columnClasses="padding widthDyna,row1-padding">
                    <h:panelGroup id="panelGroup_31D0">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{extraFieldDTO.displayText}" />
                        <h:outputText id="idar563" styleClass="red" value="*" rendered="#{extraFieldDTO.isRequiredField eq '1'}" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="firstinputselectone"   rendered="#{!dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.singleProfile}" immediate="true"
                            valueChangeListener="#{dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.showLayoutPreview}" 
                            styleClass="#{extraFieldDTO.isReadOnly eq '1' ?'disabledInputFieldSelectItem' :'enabledInputFieldSelectItem'}"
                            disabled="#{extraFieldDTO.isReadOnly eq '1'}"
                            value="#{extraFieldDTO.stringFieldValue}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.DROP_SELECTONE}"
                                id="selectItem_24" />

                            <f:selectItems
                                value="#{dropDownParserAction.getGenericLinkedKeyValueListMap(null,extraFieldDTO.dropDownSearchValue,extraFieldDTO.dropDownType,extraFieldDTO.firstLinkedDropDownType)}"
                                id="selectItems_24655" />
                            <p:ajax event="change" id="ajax_2" update="@form" immediate="true"/>
                            <f:validator validatorId="dynamicUIValidator" />
                            <f:attribute name="DYNAMICUIDATAOBJECT" value="#{extraFieldDTO}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:selectOneMenu id="firstinputselectone_SingleProfile"
                            rendered="#{dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.singleProfile}"
                            valueChangeListener="#{dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.showLayoutPreview}"
                            styleClass="#{extraFieldDTO.isReadOnly eq '1' ?'disabledInputFieldSelectItem' :'enabledInputFieldSelectItem'}"
                            disabled="#{extraFieldDTO.isReadOnly eq '1'}"
                            value="#{extraFieldDTO.stringFieldValue}">


                            <f:selectItems
                                value="#{dropDownParserAction.getGenericLinkedKeyValueListMap(null,extraFieldDTO.dropDownSearchValue,extraFieldDTO.dropDownType,extraFieldDTO.firstLinkedDropDownType)}"
                                id="selectItems_24655_SingleProfile" />
                            <f:validator validatorId="dynamicUIValidator" />
                            <f:attribute name="DYNAMICUIDATAOBJECT" value="#{extraFieldDTO}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGroup style="width:40%">
                                <h:outputText
                                    value="#{msg.HELP_DYNA_FORM_EDIT_FIELDMGMT_HELP}:&nbsp;"
                                    rendered="#{extraFieldDTO.helpText !=null}" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{extraFieldDTO.displayText}"
                                    rendered="#{extraFieldDTO.helpText !=null}" />
                                <br clear="none" />
                                <span class="garyText"> <h:outputText
                                        value="#{extraFieldDTO.helpText}"
                                        rendered="#{extraFieldDTO.helpText !=null}" /></span>
                                <br clear="none" />

                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <br clear="none" />
                        <p:message for="firstinputselectone" id="message_38"  />
                        <br clear="none" />
                        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true" id="layout_Panel" rendered="#{not empty extraFieldDTO.stringFieldValue and !facesContext.validationFailed}">
                            <div align="center">
                                <h:panelGrid id="layout_present" columns="3"
                                    rendered="#{(not empty extraFieldDTO.stringFieldValue) and ((dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.frontProfileLayout ne null) or (dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.backProfileLayout ne null))}">
                                    <p:fieldset legend="#{msg.LBL_FRONTCARD}" toggleable="false"
                                        style="width:400px;height:400px;background-color:#e6e6e6">
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            <br clear="none" />
                                            <p:spacer height="30" />
                                            <h:graphicImage id="layout_present_idar589" rendered="#{dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.frontProfileLayout ne null}"
                                                value="data:image/jpg;base64,#{dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.frontProfileLayout}" />

                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                    </p:fieldset>
                                    <p:spacer width="50" />
                                    <p:fieldset legend="#{msg.LBL_BACKCARD}" toggleable="false"
                                        style="width:400px;height:400px;background-color:#e6e6e6">
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                            <br clear="none" />
                                            <br clear="none" />
                                            <br clear="none" />
                                            <br clear="none" />
                                            <p:spacer height="40" />
                                            <h:graphicImage id="layout_present_idar590" rendered="#{dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.backProfileLayout ne null}"
                                                value="data:image/jpg;base64,#{dynamicUIPreEnrollmentAction.backProfileLayout}" />

                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                    </p:fieldset>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </div>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>


</ui:composition>
```